# List the trucks that have only been used to carry fruit

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Assume a database with schema

```
TRUCK  (license-plate, maker, model, year, mileage, max-load)
DRIVER (driver-id, name, age, address, license)
TRIP   (license-plate, driver-id, date, origin, destination, miles, cargo, cost)
```

Write Relational Algebra and SQL to list the license plate of trucks that have only been used to carry fruit.

I come up with a solution where

Relational Algebra:

[image]

SQL:

[image]

is not the correct answer. Why is that?

Comment: Please explain why you wrote what you wrote. What parts can you do? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check if a truck shipped fruit and no other type of cargo using the `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT license-plate
FROM truck
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM trip
    WHERE trip.license-plate = truck.license-plate
    AND trip.cargo = 'fruit'
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM trip
    WHERE trip.license-plate = truck.license-plate
    AND trip.cargo <> 'fruit'
)
```

Comment: great! I think this is the correct answer! or something like select all the trucks - for the one that contains fruits?

Comment: You can select all trucks that carry fruits using a JOIN or EXISTS. The problem is with the "only" fruits part. You need to remove those trucks from the result that also shipped something else hence the not exists part.

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation.  Your query only requires one table:

```
select license_plate
from trip
group by license_plate
having min(cargo) = max(cargo) and
       min(cargo) = 'fruit';
```

Your answer is not correct, because it returns trips where the cargo is fruit.  However, it does not consider the *other* trips for the same truck where the cargo may not be fruit.